# loading page inside a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html

i am creating a javascript method which loads page contents inside a div container using jquery and it works properly, but when i click at any button inside the div itself, it redirects to new page?

that's the method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('a').click(function() {
                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                $("#content").fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $("#content").load(page, function () {
                        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
```

anyone can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding only element present on page loadnot ones created afterwards by using click if you use this instead it should work

```
$('a').live('click', function(){});
```

Basically live will bind to all a tags even newly created ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should use iframe instead. When you use a div like page, you just load content on it, not load page.

Comment: but, can i keep the fadeIn/fadeOut effect in iframes? because it's important

Comment: I don't know, you can try it by ourself. ^^. Waiting for your result